# Combinig past and present tenses together

Tags: idioms, past-tense, present-tense, writing, idioms-in-context

I've made a discovery that a phrase **to be out of the question** is an idiom, meaning to *be an event that cannot possibly happen*.

In a book (Charlotte Bronte - "Jane Eyre") I approached the following sentence - "*the cold winter wind had brought with it clouds so sombre, and a rain so penetrating, that further outdoor exercise **was now** out of the question.*".

I got the idea of not being able to do outdoor exercises while it's raining. The problem is that I can't comprehend the usage of both **was** and **now** at the same time - **was**, which is the past tense of the verb *to be*, and **now**, an adverb of time, meaning that something happens at present. I can't link them together to make it understandable and "usable".

Could you please, tell me if that is something that relates to how stories are told, a special way of writing English; or it just a regular sentence with tenses combined. Could you also provide an explanation in terms of a timeline if my latter idea is right?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You seem to have focused on one meaning of the adverb "now" ("meaning that something happens at present") without considering other meanings. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/now), for example, lists seven meanings.

Answer (score 1):

'Now' can be used used when talking or writing about past events, to describe a new situation or event - the weather became so bad that a new situation arose (further outdoor exercise was now impossible).